# Why does latexindent fail to properly indent this code?

Tags: latexindent

Latexindent fails to properly indent this code (it removes all indentation, when it should rather leave the indentation alone, or minimally modify it at least).

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand*{\fixcref}{
    % Allow spaces in `cref` command.
    \cs_set_eq:Nc \bers_cref:nn { @cref }
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn \bers_cref:nn { nx }
    \cs_set_protected:cpn { @cref } ##1 ##2
        {
            \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_bers_cref_seq { , } { ##2 }
            \bers_cref:nx { ##1 } { \seq_use:Nn \l_bers_cref_seq { , } }
        }
    \seq_new:N \l_bers_cref_seq
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: It seems the combination of `##1 ##2` and the single `{` on the next line creates the problem. With regular arguments (`#1 #2`) or something else on the next line (`\a{` for example) the indentation is ok. Looks like a bug, maybe you can post an issue in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/issues).

Comment: @Marijn Thanks. What would the work-around be for now, i.e., somehow telling latexindent to not bother formatting this block?

Comment: If you are willing to modify the code then you can add `%\begin{noindent}` and `%\end{noindent}` around the command, this will stop Latexindent from formatting it.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks. I'll do that for the time being.

Comment: Resolved on issue tracker :)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up opening a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/issues/239) for this, and @cmhughes, the author of latexindent, kindly got back to me promptly. He provided a fix for the time being, and also indicated that he would be incorporating this into the future default settings for latexindent.

For the time being, add this to your `localSettings.yaml`. It allows "escaped" arguments of the form `##1` between braces.

```yaml
commandCodeBlocks:
    stringsAllowedBetweenArguments:
      - 
        amalgamate: 1
      - '\#\#\d'
```

Comment: no need for the addition to `localSettings.yaml` as of V3.9 (https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/releases/tag/V3.9)